# Argument of type 'MatSort | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MatSort'

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, angular-material, angular16

I try to get sorted data from MatTableDataSource using this code:

```
this.source = this.dataSource.sortData(this.dataSource.filteredData,this.dataSource.sort);
```

but I got this error:

> Argument of type 'MatSort | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MatSort'.Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'MatSort

I am using Angular 16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error highlights that `this.dataSource.sort` is `MatSort | null` type, while the second parameter in the `sortData` method expects the value with `MatSort` type.

You can check `this.dataSource.sort` is not `null` before calling the `this.dataSource.sortData` method.

```
if (this.dataSource.sort)
  this.source = this.dataSource.sortData(this.dataSource.filteredData, this.dataSource.sort);
```

Reference: [API reference for Angular Material table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api)